# Estimating the average marginal effect of binary and continuous coefficients in logit model R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, margins, marginal-effects

Using data from the National Health Interview Survey, I am hoping to analyze the average marginal effect a variety of demographic factors have on the predicted probability of having hypertension using a logistic regression. To clarify, by average marginal effect I mean that I want to be computing the marginal effect at the mean of every X (like the STATA output).

My issue is that I have both binary and continuous independent variables, but from what I've read, it doesn't make sense to evaluate the binary variables at their mean, since it's either a 0 or 1. I don't know how to make the regression run where I can evaluate the continuous variables at their mean, but not the binary ones. Here is the code I have so far.

```
#Here I create a data frame of the means of the continuous variables 
mean_df=df %>% select(c(AGE,BMICALC,FAMSIZE,YEARSONJOB,HOURSWRK)) %>% summarise_all(mean)


#here is my regression, variables here not in the line of code above are binary 
logit_margin_diabetes <- glm(DIABETES~scale(AGE)+scale(IMMIGRANT)+scale(HOURSWRK)+scale(BELOW_TWICE_POVERTY)
+scale(BMICALC)+scale(FEMALE)+scale(FAMSIZE)+scale(EDUC_1)+scale(EDUC_2)+scale(EDUC_3)+
scale(EDUC_4)+scale(SMOKE)+scale(MARRIED)+scale(HISP)+scale(AFR_AM)+scale(WHITE), data = df,family="binomial")

#This is the stage where I want to apply the logit so it is evaluated at the means of the continuous variables. But I don't know what to do about the binary variables 
marg_mean<-margins(logit_margin_diabetes,data=mean_df)
summary(marg_mean)
```

Apologies, it was difficult for me to produce and MRE, since I don't know of a dataset in R that has this sort of information. But if anyone can provide any advice that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here is the modified output per the comment below. But I would like the output to show the SE,AME,and p values too

```
margins(logit_margin, at=list(AGE=35.93349,BMICALC=26.90704, FAMSIZE=2.495413, YEARSONJOB=4.538336,
                                        HOURSWRK=32.53768,IMMIGRANT=1,
                                        BELOW_TWICE_POVERTY=1, FEMALE=1,
                                       EDUC_1=1,EDUC_2=1,EDUC_3=1,EDUC_4=1,
                                        SMOKE=1,MARRIED=1,HISP=1,
                                        AFR_AM=1,WHITE=1))
summary(marg_mean)
```

[image]

This is a photo of the new output I see after running summary(marg_mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margins` package takes care of this automatically if you declare a variable to be a factor. See the [subsetting section of the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) or you can [inspect the source code](https://github.com/leeper/margins/blob/main/R/dydx.R#L149) to see that marginal effects are computed as differences for factor variables.

Note that the default setting for `margins` is to compute the "average marginal effect", and *not* the "marginal effect at the mean". IMO, the default setting is best in most cases, but if you insist on considering a "synthetic" average observation, it is easy to do with the `at` argument of the `margins` function.

Code example. In the first case, `vs` is treated as a continuous variable. In the second, `vs` is treated as a binary variable.

```r
library(margins)

mod1 <- glm(am ~ hp + vs, data=mtcars, family=binomial)
mod2 <- glm(am ~ hp + factor(vs), data=mtcars, family=binomial)

margins(mod1)
#> Average marginal effects
#> glm(formula = am ~ hp + vs, family = binomial, data = mtcars)
#>        hp       vs
#>  -0.00203 -0.03193

margins(mod2)
#> Average marginal effects
#> glm(formula = am ~ hp + factor(vs), family = binomial, data = mtcars)
#>        hp      vs1
#>  -0.00203 -0.03154
```

Edit: Here's an example of the `at` argument:

```r
margins(mod1, at=list(hp=200, vs=0))
```

Comment: Great thank you Vincent! All this information is very helpful. So just to clarify, in the last line of code you set vs=0, I should set all binary variables equal to 0 here?

Comment: Well, it depends *which* marginal effect you care about. Say there are two binary variables `x` and `w` in your model, you might well care about the marginal effect of `x` when `w=1`. In that case, you would set `at=list(w=1)`. But otherwise, it sounds like you got the right idea.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense! Great. One other question, I applied your suggestion with my data, and it did run, but didn't produce the output I am hoping for. I am hoping the final table will provide me with each of the coefficients along with their p-value, standard error, etc. Any ideas on how to do that? I modified my post to give you a sense of what I did. Thank you again!

Comment: Can you try to run my code and then do `summary(margins(mod1))`. For me, this gives the AME, SE, z, p, lower, upper.

Comment: Yes that does run properly. But I'm not able to get it to work when you add the "at" argument in your example: margins(mod1, at=list(hp=200, vs=0))

Comment: If it helps, the error I receive is: "Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]"

Comment: No, sorry. I can't help diagnose if I don't have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) Also, once you find one, it's best to open a new question because this seems like different problem than the original one. It's not ideal to edit an original question (akin to moving the goal post).